# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS for Wordpress when using Loadbalancer and SSL encryption on Digitalocean

Tags: wordpress, ssl, digital-ocean

I have a wordpress installation on a digitalocean droplet. The traffic to the droplet is routed via a digitalocean loadbalancer.

The site works perfectly fine if I call it without SSL. However, once I change the siteurl to HTTPS and call the site via its HTTPS domain, I receive ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Just some additional info which might help:

- I have no redirect plugin installed.
- The Loadbalancer communicates with the droplet via a private network without SSL
- The loadbalancer's forwarding rule is HTTPS on port 443 -> HTTP on port 80
- Apache is listening on port 80, SSL engine off
- site url in wp_options and wp_sitemeta is set to HTTPS://DOMAIN.DE (there is also no mismatching siturl in wp_config)

Any ideas how to tackle this issue?

cURL Output

```
:~$ curl -IlLk https://DOMAIN.de
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
date: Fri, 16 Jun 2023 19:00:08 GMT
server: Apache/2.4.54 (Ubuntu)
x-redirect-by: WordPress
location: https://DOMAIN.de/
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
transfer-encoding: chunked

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
date: Fri, 16 Jun 2023 19:00:09 GMT
server: Apache/2.4.54 (Ubuntu)
x-redirect-by: WordPress
location: https://DOMAIN.de/
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
transfer-encoding: chunked

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
date: Fri, 16 Jun 2023 19:00:09 GMT
server: Apache/2.4.54 (Ubuntu)
x-redirect-by: WordPress
location: https://DOMAIN.de/
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
transfer-encoding: chunked

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
date: Fri, 16 Jun 2023 19:00:10 GMT
server: Apache/2.4.54 (Ubuntu)
x-redirect-by: WordPress
location: https://DOMAIN.de/
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
transfer-encoding: chunked
enter code here
```

.htaccess file

```
#BEGIN WordPress Multisite
# Using subfolder network type: https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/htaccess/#multisite

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# END WordPress Multisite
```

vHost config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
SSLEngine off
ServerName DOMAIN.de
ServerAlias www.DOMAIN.de
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/DOMAIN
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<Directory /var/www/DOMAIN>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```